# JSON XMLHttpRequest POST/PUT to Cherrypy application - getting no data

Tags: javascript, python, json, xmlhttprequest, cherrypy

I want to create a Singlepage Application following REST principles. I have managed to make both GET and DELETE work, but i also need to PUT or POST data.

After failing for some time, i looked around and found some sample code here https://gist.github.com/EtienneR/2f3ab345df502bd3d13e
which, first of all, taught me that setting a request header may be helpful. With that done, however, and following the exact example, I'm still getting "None" for the field i expect to receive data on.
I may be missing something absolutely basic, and looking around some more i just can't find out what it is.

on the javascript side i've got:

```
update_px (path_spl, success_ppl, fail_ppl, formdata) {
    this.success_p = success_ppl;
    this.fail_p = fail_ppl;

    var data = {};
    data.firstname = "John";
    data.lastname  = "Snow";
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", path_spl, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "201") {
            console.table(users);
        } else {
            console.error(users);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(json);

}
```

and on the python side of things:

```
def POST(self, path_spl="NoPathError", id = None, data_opl=None):
  print("POST called with path_spl " + path_spl )
  if(id != None) :
     print(" and id " + id)
  print (data_opl)
  #process data
  return ' '
```

The method is exposed; output shows I'm receiving the correct path and ID, but data is just None even after swapping in this sample code i found.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: I would start by adding *kwargs to the Python POST function to see what data is sent.

Comment: You should decorate the handler with `json_in` tool and retrieve data as dict from `cherrypy.request.json`

Comment: You can also use `cherrypy.tools.json_out` and the dict you return from the handler with be turned into json automatically.

Comment: Oh, and btw your js would look nicer if you used Fetch API

Answer (score -1):

I have found a way to get it to work.

1) ** was missing on the expected data - that alone didn't help, now i was getting an empty dict instead of None

2) i replaced the content type; the header is now

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

with that, i am receiving:

> {'{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Snow"}': ''}

Which actually leads me into another question - how did {"firstname":"John","lastname":Snow"} become a key with an empty value during json-ification? But anyway. That's for another day to find out; i can work with what i'm getting now.

Comment: Use json_in and json_out tools on back-end side.